# Pyautogui - click on image: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm writing a script to fill a monthly tax form using pyautogui.

There are 2 images to be clicked on.

#### Issue

I'm getting the following error on the second one:

```
PS C:\Users\Rodrigo\OneDrive\Documentos\Python> & C:/Users/Rodrigo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Rodrigo/OneDrive/Documentos/Python/SIFERE/saf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rodrigo\OneDrive\Documentos\Python\SIFERE\saf.py", line 16, in <module>
    pyautogui.click('SIFERE/agrega_saf.png')
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodrigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 980, in click  
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
PS C:\Users\Rodrigo\OneDrive\Documentos\Python>
```

#### Code

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(3)
anio='2015' 
mes='abril'
secuencia='1'
monto='1234.56'

pyautogui.click('SIFERE/periodo.png')
pyautogui.press('tab')  
pyautogui.write(anio)
pyautogui.press('tab')  
pyautogui.write(mes)
pyautogui.press('tab')  
pyautogui.write(secuencia)
pyautogui.press('tab')  
pyautogui.write(monto)
pyautogui.click('SIFERE/agrega_saf.png')
```

I've copied that exact same line to another py file and it works, but not on this one.

Comment: Have a look to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442076/pyautogui-typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-nonetype-object), does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to locate the given images on your screen.

Therefor PyAutoGUI has the function [`locateOnScreen(image)`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) which returns a `location`. If the image was found, the location is defined otherwise it's `None`.

See also: [How to detect an image and click it with pyautogui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864949/how-to-detect-an-image-and-click-it-with-pyautogui)

Try to locate the given images first. If they were found, then continue with your input.

#### Code

```py
import pyautogui, time

anio='2015' 
mes='abril'
secuencia='1'
monto='1234.56'


def find_image_or_exit(image):
    i = 1
    while location == None and i < 3:  # try max 3 times (for 9 seconds)
        time.sleep(3)  # wait 3 seconds
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image)
        i += 1
    if location == None:
        print(f"Sorry! Image {image} not found on screen. Aborting!")
        exit()
    return location
    

def enter_period():
    location = find_image_or_exit('SIFERE/periodo.png')
    pyautogui.click(location)

    pyautogui.press('tab')  
    pyautogui.write(anio)
    pyautogui.press('tab')  
    pyautogui.write(mes)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.write(secuencia)
    pyautogui.press('tab')  
    pyautogui.write(monto)


def add_saf():
    location = find_image_or_exit('SIFERE/agrega_saf.png')
    pyautogui.click(location)


# main steps
enter_period()
add_saf()
```