# I am not exactly sure why pyautogui is not locating it. It crashes and It instantaneously just closes the window

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
from tkinter import Tk  
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

clipyy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('clipy.png')
clipy = pyautogui.center(clipyy)

pyautogui.leftClick(clipy)
```

This is my code. Could you please find the answer?

I tried the `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('clipy.png')` but it simply does not work

Comment: its not pyautogui.leftClick() 
its pyautogui.click() and you can pass x and y to click method

Comment: checkout https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks 
also check if clipyy has found the img you are looking for then pass it to pyautogui.center()
you can place it in an if clause

Comment: 1. [PyAutoGUI Mouse control](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks)
2. [How to detect an image and click it with pyautogui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864949/how-to-detect-an-image-and-click-it-with-pyautogui)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import pyautogui

clipyy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('clipy.png')
if clipyy:
    print("found Image")
    clipy = pyautogui.center(clipyy)
    pyautogui.click(x=clipy.x, y=clipy.y)
else:
    print("Image not found")
```

Comment: No, it did not work. It gave me the same error

Comment: share error data maybe there is a problem with something else